# What can OLS with a Box-Cox transformed dependent variable tell me?

Tags: least-squares, linear-model, data-transformation, regression-coefficients, boxcox-transformation

Just to ellaborate: I’m doing an OLS-test to determine the following things:

1. Do my independent variables have a significant effect on the dependent variable?
2. What’s the direction of the effect of my significant independent variables (positive/negative)?
3. What’s the order of my independent variables by strength of effect? (e.g.: Which independent variable has the strongest effect, and which one has the weakest effect?)

Now, I know that there are other statistical models that could come into play, but for all other reasons, I decided to make OLS work if possible.

Since my residuals are definitely not normal (but I would like to interpret p-values, etc. from my model), I’m thinking of using a Box-Cox transformation. However, I’m a bit confused about whether I can interpret the coefficients of the significant independent variables after doing a Box-Cox transformation on the dependent variable to answer my research questions. Again, I’m not looking to build a predictive model with precise predictive power – I’m just looking to:

1. Establish whether an independent variable has a statistically significant effect on the dependent variable
2. Establish the direction of this effect
3. Establish whether one independent variable has a stronger effect than another one (without saying anything about ‘how much stronger” that effect is)
   Thanks!

Since the question has been closed until I provide more details, I'll do that now:

My dependent variable is a percentage (the percentage of a certain bacteria in various stool-samples). I'm curious about how to interpret the OLS results if I decide to do a Box-Cox transformation on this dependent variable (with a lambda value around 0.2 - 0.5).

My independent variables are things like age, gender (dummy), weekly average amount of milk consumed, BMI-score, and a few others. After the Box-Cox transformation of my dependent variable, I'm curious if I can make statements like the following (based on the OLS results):

- "BMI and age have a significant effect on the percentage of X-bacteria"
- "Based on their standardized coefficients (or should I look at something else??), BMI is negatively associated with the percentage of X-bacteria, while age is positively associated with this percentage"
- "Based on the absolute value of their standardized coefficients (again: am I looking in the wrong direction?), the effect of BMI on the percentage of X-bacteria is stronger than the effect of age"

As you can see, I'm looking to make broad statements (so NOT predictions) about my original dependent variable, despite having transformed it using the Box-Cox method. Also, I'm planning on using the various standardized coefficients of my independent variables to make these broad statements.

To summarize:

1. I want to determine which independent variables have a significant effect. Since the residuals of my dependent variable are non-normal, I assume that I can't trust the p-values I get from that regression. But my question is: can I trust the p-values after the Box-Cox transformation IF the residuals look normal?
2. I want to know the direction of the effect of my various independent variables. Can I make this assessment by looking at their standardized coefficients in the regression with the Box-Cox transformed dependent variable (whether the coefficients are positive or negative)? Or is there any other way to determine this?
3. I want to know which of the significant independent variables has a "stronger" effect on the dependent variable. Can I do this by looking at the standardized coefficients (the absolute value) of the independent variable?

I don't know how to be any more clear than this. Please note, that I'm kind of a newbie, but I'm trying my best!
Thank you for all of the answers and your patience!

Comment: The meaning of (3) is vague and uncertain, because it depends on what you might mean by "strength" of an explanatory variable and how you propose to measure it.  Otherwise, your questions have a simple straightforward answer if you view the Box-Cox transformation as merely choosing a different way of expressing the response numerically.  From that perspective, this is plain vanilla OLS and all calculations, interpretations, *etc.* are the same as they have ever been.

Comment: @whuber I think the OP is wondering what happens if the dependent variable is originally on an easily interpretable scale (in "natural" units), then mapped to a different one where the "natural" units--and hence interpretation in terms of those--might be lost.

Comment: @statmerkur It's hard to tell.  I am concerned now about the possibility of multiple conflicting interpretations of this question, so I looks best to close it until clarification is offered.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful answers! After clarifying the question even further, can you give me a clarification of your answers as well? Thanks!

Comment: @whuber so you mean that I can interpret the effects of independent variables on the original dependent variable based on the results of the OLS made with the Box-Cox transformed dependent variable? I did a bit of clarification to my original post, but I'd be curious to see if what you're saying applies in my specific case.

Comment: Yes.  Imagine, for instance, that you were measuring plant growth in some way and atmospheric temperature by filling a bladder with air and measuring the bladder's diameter.  That could be done very precisely and, with proper calibration, accurately.  You would likely find that the Box-Cox transformation of the diameter with parameter $3$ would give a good regression model for plant growth (also suitably transformed). This would be telling you, of course, that the cube of the diameter is the "real" way to measure temperature.

Comment: @whuber thanks I think I understand! So if I understand you correctly (sorry if I'm overstating the obvious) if I use a Box-Cox transformation on my DV (only my DV), then:
1) The IVs that are significant in this regression are the ones that are actually significant in the relationship
2) The +/- sign of the standardized coefficients of my IVs can determine the direction of effect of my IVs on my original DV (+/-)
3) Based on the absolute value of the standardized coefficients of my IVs, I can put them in order from strongest to weakest.

Is this correct or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It's basically right. (2) follows because the Box-Cox transformations respect the ordering of real numbers. (3) is by *fiat,* but it's a reasonable way to *define* what you mean by "strong" and "weak." The language of (1) might be a little misleading insofar as it incorrectly suggests that the "relationship" has some definition independent of how you express and model your variables.  It is possible for one choice to give a non-significant result and another choice to give a significant one.  Statistical analysis is a principled way to draw conclusions from your data *and your assumptions.*

Comment: @whuber Thank you so much, you're amazing! Literally saved my research project by clearing these up for me. Thank you!